# State Space Representation of a discharge through a gate

Tags: control-theory, mathematical-modeling

I have one equation that describes the discharge through a radial gate placed in a hydro power plant, given by
$$
Q = \frac{dV(t)}{dt} = C_g \cdot D \cdot L \cdot \sqrt{2\cdot g \cdot H_g(t)}
$$
where
$$
H_g(t) = H(t) - \frac{D}{2}
$$

- $Q$ is the discharge through the gate with the unit $[m^3/s]$.
- $C_g$ is a dimensionless discharge coefficient, dependant on various features of the design such as gate lip angle and shape, gate radius and trunnion pin point height.
- $D$ is gate opening with the unit $[m]$.
- $L$ is the total length of the gate with the unit $[m]$
- $g$ is the acceleration of gravity with the unit $[m/s^2]$
- $H$ is the height of the water with the unit $[m]$.

[Image of the radial gate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhAbG.jpg)

I'm trying to design a control system for the gate, so the height of the water will always stay at 116 m. I am having difficulties to find the state space model for this equation.

My idea is to choose

- Control Input: $u(t) = D$
- State: $x_1(t) = H(t)$

Therefore I get

$$
Q = \frac{dV(t)}{dt} = C_g L u(t) \sqrt{2gx_1(t) - gu(t)}
$$

I am wondering if I should also choose $Q$ as a state, so I would get $x_2(t) = Q(t)$?

How can I set this equation up on the form
$$
\bf{\dot x} = \bf{A} \bf x + \bf B \bf u \\
\bf y = \bf C \bf x + \bf D \bf u
$$
?

I feel this is so complicated because I have $x_1(t)$ and $u(t)$ under the square root. I don't know how to compensate for that?

Do I need to do some integral or differential magics to this formula?

I had one idea of changing the formula to get
$$
H = \frac{Q^2}{D^2}\left(\frac{1}{C_g^2 \cdot L^2 \cdot 2g}\right) + D\left(\frac{D}{2}\right)
$$
and maybe differentiate that? Can I do something with the formula like this?

When I will figure this out, my next step is to apply the control law $u(t) = -\bf K \bf x(t)$ to make a feedback loop for this system. All help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with [linearization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearization#Linearization_of_a_multivariable_function)?

Comment: Hi Kwin, yes I am, I will try to linearize the system and see what I will get. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

The dynamics is highly nonlinear. I don't think it can be expressed in the standard linear  State-space representation $\dot{x} = A x + B u$. However, we can probably consider this design approach:

Assuming that $V = A H$, then

$$ \dot{H} = \frac{1}{A} C_{D} L u \sqrt{2 g H - g u} $$

$$ \dot{H} = \frac{1}{A} C_{D} L u \sqrt{g \left(2 H - u\right)} $$

$$ \dot{H} = \frac{1}{A} C_{D} L u \sqrt{g} \sqrt{2 H - u} $$

Grouping $\frac{1}{A} C_{D} L \sqrt{g} = \mathcal{C}_{1} > 0$ as a constant, then

$$ \dot{H} = \mathcal{C}_{1} u \sqrt{2 H - u} $$

Consider the Lyapunov function candidate

$$ V(H) = \frac{1}{2} H^{2}, \quad \forall \; H > 0 $$

The derivative of $V(H)$ along the trajectories of the system is given by

$$ \dot{V}(H) = H \dot{H} $$

$$ \dot{V}(H) = H \mathcal{C}_{1} u \sqrt{2 H - u} $$

If the control law $u = - k H$ where $k > 0$ is applied, then

$$ \dot{V}(H) = - k \mathcal{C}_{1} H^{2} \sqrt{2 H + k H} \\ $$

$$ \dot{V}(H) = - k \mathcal{C}_{1} H^{2} \sqrt{\left(2 + k\right) H} $$

$$ \dot{V}(H) = - k \mathcal{C}_{1} \sqrt{2 + k} H^{2} \sqrt{H} $$

Grouping $k \mathcal{C}_{1} \sqrt{2 + k} = \mathcal{C}_{2} > 0$ as another constant, then

$$ \dot{V}(H) = - \mathcal{C}_{2} H^{2} \sqrt{H} < 0, \quad \forall \; H > 0 $$

If $H_{r}$ is the desired reference water height, then the proposed control law becomes

$$ u = - k \left(H - H_{r}\right) $$

The value selection of the gain $k$ depends on how fast the motorized actuator can open/close the gate.

**Addendum**: To implement the proposed control law, one has to look into this term

$$ \sqrt{2 H - u} = \sqrt{2 H + k \left(H - H_{r}\right)} $$

because the square root of any real number cannot be negative. Thus, solving the inequality

$$ 2 H + k \left(H - H_{r}\right) \geq 0 $$

shows that water level $H$ has to be retained at the minimum level of

$$ H_{\text{min}} = \frac{k H_{r}}{k + 2} $$

In other words, if the desired water level is to be regulated at $H_{r} = 116$ m, and $k = 1$ is a constant, then the minimum water level at the hydropower plant would be

$$ H_{\text{min}} = \frac{116}{3} \approx 38.66 \; \text{m} $$

If the hydropower plant engineers can guarantee that the water level won't go below $H_{\text{min}}$ during operation, then the proposed control law should work, in theory.

If the hydropower plant engineers need to safeguard the operation, where $H_{\text{min}}$ can be unpredictable due to some unforeseen circumstances, then the gain $k$ should be varied according to certain water level $H$.

One possible way is to introduce a piecewise function for the gain $k$

$$ k(H) = \begin{cases}
\frac{2 \beta H}{H_{r} - H} & \text{if }\; 0 < H < H^{*} \\
k_{0} & \text{if }\; H \geq H^{*} 
\end{cases} $$
where $0 < \beta < 1$ and the gain saturates at $k = k_{0}$, a constant, when $H^{*} = \frac{k_{0} H_{r}}{2 \beta + k_{0}}$, which is found by solving the equation

$$ \frac{2 \beta H}{H_{r} - H} = k_{0} $$

For example, if $\beta = 0.5$ and $k_{0} = 1$, then the gain saturates at $k(58) = 1$. So, when the water level drops below $H^{*} = 58$ m, then the gain $k$ will automatically adjust according to the schedule

$$ k_{\downarrow 58} = \frac{2 \beta H}{H_{r} - H} $$

Note that $\beta = 0.5$ is selected in this example so that $H^{*} > H_{\text{min}}$ gives a safety margin of approximately $20$ m. This ensures the square root of positive number for $0 < H < 58$

$$ \sqrt{2 H + k \left(H - H_{r}\right)} = \sqrt{2 H \left(1 - \beta\right)} $$

because $1 - \beta > 0$. If the safety margin needs to be increased, then $\beta$ has to be lowered.

Comment: Xega, thank you for the help I higly appreciate it. It seems like you have a deep understanding of this subject! I'm inspired! I will try to keep this question updated if I will get some interesting results.

Comment: The control law with $H_r$ is not correct as it can make the term in the square root negative. In general it is fallacious to generalize linear control laws like this in the nonlinear setting without calculations.

Comment: KBS, thank you for your input, i will consider it.

Comment: Hi Grétar, I'm not a hydropower plant engineer. Moreover, the proposed control law $u = - K H$ was your original idea to begin with. I just tested if it works under the Lyapunov stability theory, which is a gold standard test for most nonlinear systems. In most cases, engineers usually avoid complicated unfamiliar control structure and keep the control design as simple as possible.

Comment: Yes, that's true, it was my idea. I think I should look into nonlinear control theory and do some reading about that, and as Kwin mentioned above, maybe I can just linerize the system around some point where it can be stable. I'm going to look into this and see what I will get. Again, thank you for the help and the inspiration! Very useful!